# Using mathtext parser to output a svg file

Tags: matplotlib, svg, blender

## Context

I'm looking for a simple way to import properly typeset mathematics (with LaTeX) into [blender](https://www.blender.org/). A solution for this [has already been given](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72514/765). But that means getting out of blender, using multiple tools and then going back to blender and importing the whole thing.

## Blender comes with Python and can import svg

I'd like to find an other way and blender has a set of powerful tools based on Python. I was thinking: can I make Python parse some TeX input and then generate a svg (virtual) file *inside* blender. That would solve the problem.

## matplotlib "emulates" TeX

It is possible to [install any Python library](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41258/765) and use it inside blender. So this made me think of a possible "hack" of matplotlib.

[`mathtext`](https://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) is a module that provides a parser for strings with TeX-like syntax for mathematical expressions. `svg` is one of the available "backends".

Consider the following snippet.

```
import matplotlib.mathtext as mathtext

parser = mathtext.MathTextParser('svg')
 
t = parser.parse(r'$\int_{0}^{t} x^2 dx = \frac{t^3}{3}$')
```

`t` is a tuple that has all the information needed. But I can't find a way (in the [backend api](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_svg_api.html)) to convert it to a (virtual) svg file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Removed the `pyparsing` tag and added `svg` tag, since this is really about exporting mathtext parsed output to svg. The fact that mathtext uses pyparsing does not really have much to do with the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matplotlib needs a figure (and currently also a canvas) to actually be able to render anything. So in order to produce an svg file whose only content is a text (a mathtext formula) you still need a figure and a canvas and the text needs to actually reside inside the figure, which can be achieved by `fig.text(..)`.
Then you can save the figure to svg via `fig.savefig(..)`. Using the `bbox_inches="tight"` option ensures the figure to be clipped to the extent of the text. And setting the facecolor to a transparent color removes the figure's background patch.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

fig.text(.5, .5, r'$\int_{0}^{t} x^2 dx = \frac{t^3}{3}$', fontsize=40)
fig.savefig("output.svg", bbox_inches="tight", facecolor=(1,1,1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! BTW, do you know where I can find a documentation about the objects stored inside my tuple `t`?

Comment: What kind of information do you need and for what reason?